# I lose my newly inserted row when I cancel the BeforeRowUpdate event

Tags: c#

I am using a WinUltraGrid to enter new rows into our database. When a new row is being entered and the user finishes entering the data, I am checking for null values in the BeforeRowUpdate event which occurs when the user leaves that row by clicking the save button or by clicking another row in the grid. If any of the columns are null then I set e.cancel to true to cancel the event after displaying a user friendly message.

My problem is that when I return to the grid, my partially entered row is gone and I have to start over. Any ideas on how to keep the partial data in the new row at the top of my grid? I am using VS 2008 and C# .Net.

Thanks

Comment: If you are canceling the entire BeforeRowUpdate event, it makes sense that the action of adding a row has been canceled and so no row will show up.

Answer (score 0):

In general (I don't have experience with the WinUltraGrid component), setting Cancel to true on an event args object does just what you're seeing - cancels the row update event. I suspect that the data is probably rebound after that, clearing the row. What you'd probably need to do is to set up some sort of post-processing after you set the cancel (though timing could be tricky, if the component is rebinding under the covers). What I assume might work would be to save the non-null values in a custom object or dictionary, then after the event is cancelled, go back, check the dictionary/custom object, and push the values into the new row again, setting focus as needed.

Comment: I agree.  It's behaving as expected, actually, and in all likelihood it is re-databinding and thus killing your partly-entered data.  Regular GridViews remember the edit row and typed data just fine if you stop them with manually written code.  It may be difficult or impossible to prevent the databinding if it is happening due to custom WinUltraGrid code.  You might have to resort to what Shelby suggested and roll your own ViewState restore, essentially.  Be better if you could let the ViewState due it for you, though.

Comment: Thanks. I had thought about retianing the data and then reinserting the partial data into a new row giving the impression that the row is still there after it is invalidated. I am going to try this approach. Thanks